# How to combine date ranges in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

I have an array that have start_date, end_date and price Eg.

```
/* date formate 'yyyy-mm-dd' */

$existingRanges = [
  ['start_date' => '2023-11-22', 'end_date' => '2023-11-30', 'price' => 200],
  ['start_date' => '2023-12-10', 'end_date' => '2023-12-14', 'price' => 100],
  ['start_date' => '2023-12-15', 'end_date' => '2023-12-20', 'price' => 100],
  ['start_date' => '2023-12-21', 'end_date' => '2023-12-27', 'price' => 100],
  ['start_date' => '2024-01-05', 'end_date' => '2024-01-05', 'price' => 600],
  ['start_date' => '2024-01-06', 'end_date' => '2024-01-07', 'price' => 700],
  ['start_date' => '2024-01-08', 'end_date' => '2024-01-20', 'price' => 700],
  ['start_date' => '2024-01-21', 'end_date' => '2024-01-31', 'price' => 100],
];
```

I want here to merge all the dates which are next to each other but have the same prices ie ***2024-01-06*** to ***2024-01-07*** and ***2024-01-08*** to ***2024-01-20*** these two date ranges are next to each other and their prices are the same so it should be ***2024-01-06*** to ***2024-01-20*** and price 700.

Array example of my results.

```
$results = [
  ['start_date' => '2023-11-22', 'end_date' => '2023-11-30', 'price' => 200],
  ['start_date' => '2023-12-10', 'end_date' => '2023-12-27', 'price' => 100],
  ['start_date' => '2024-01-05', 'end_date' => '2024-01-05', 'price' => 600],
  ['start_date' => '2024-01-06', 'end_date' => '2024-01-20', 'price' => 700],
  ['start_date' => '2024-01-21', 'end_date' => '2024-01-31', 'price' => 100],
];
```

The code/logic I tried with

```
function mergeDateRanges($p_arrDateranges) {
  // sort by start date
  /* usort($p_arrDateranges, function($a1, $a2) {
    return $a1['start_date'] === $a2['start_date'] ? 0 : ($a1['start_date'] < $a2['start_date'] ? -1 : 1);
   }); */

   $finalArray = [];
   $arrMerged = array();
   $arrLastDR = null;
   foreach ($p_arrDateranges as $arrDR) {

     if ($arrLastDR === null) {
       $arrLastDR = $arrDR;
       continue;
     }

     if(!$arrMerged) {
      array_push($arrMerged, $arrLastDR);
     }

     $endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $arrLastDR['end_date']);
     $sLastDateE_1 = $endDate->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d');

     if (strtotime($arrDR['start_date']) < strtotime($sLastDateE_1) && $arrDR['price'] == $arrLastDR['price']) {
       array_push($finalArray, [
         'start_date' => $arrDR['start_date'], 
         'end_date' => $arrLastDR['end_date'], 
         'price' => 0
       ]);
     } else {
       array_push($finalArray, $arrDR);
     }

     $arrLastDR = $arrDR;
     array_push($arrMerged, $arrLastDR);
     //print_r($arrLastDR);
 }

 return $finalArray;
}

mergeDateRanges($existingRanges);
```

This is returning different results So please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: So it is assumed that the array elements have been sorted by start date, right ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: An upvote from me for showing what you've tried this time. See, we do notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the time comparison of the previous end date equals current start date, along with the price check, then only update the end date of `$arrLastDR` to the current one's end date(we can call this merging).

If they don't match, this merge segment was only valid till this index. So, add that to `$finalArray` and start a new `$arrLastDR` with the current one.

---

So change the below

```
if(!$arrMerged) {
      array_push($arrMerged, $arrLastDR);
     }

     $endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $arrLastDR['end_date']);
     $sLastDateE_1 = $endDate->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d');

     if (strtotime($arrDR['start_date']) < strtotime($sLastDateE_1) && $arrDR['price'] == $arrLastDR['price']) {
       array_push($finalArray, [
         'start_date' => $arrDR['start_date'], 
         'end_date' => $arrLastDR['end_date'], 
         'price' => 0
       ]);
     } else {
       array_push($finalArray, $arrDR);
     }

     $arrLastDR = $arrDR;
     array_push($arrMerged, $arrLastDR);
```

**to**

```
 $endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $arrLastDR['end_date']);
     $sLastDateE_1 = $endDate->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d');

     if (strtotime($arrDR['start_date']) == strtotime($sLastDateE_1) && $arrDR['price'] == $arrLastDR['price']) {
        $arrLastDR['end_date'] = $arrDR['end_date'];
     }else{
        array_push($finalArray, $arrLastDR);
        $arrLastDR = $arrDR;
     }
     
    }
    
    if($arrLastDR !== null){
        array_push($finalArray, $arrLastDR);
    }
```

[**Live Demo**](https://3v4l.org/TfZlr)

**Note:** No need of any explicit sorting since you already confirmed that the input is in a sorted manner.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate solution:

```
<?php

/*

Question Author: Hola
Question Answerer: Jacob Mulquin
Question: How to combine date ranges in PHP
URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77555919/how-to-combine-date-ranges-in-php
Tags: php, algorithm

*/

$existingRanges = [
  ['start_date' => '2023-11-22', 'end_date' => '2023-11-30', 'price' => 200],
  ['start_date' => '2023-12-10', 'end_date' => '2023-12-14', 'price' => 100],
  ['start_date' => '2023-12-15', 'end_date' => '2023-12-20', 'price' => 100],
  ['start_date' => '2023-12-22', 'end_date' => '2023-12-27', 'price' => 100], // I modified this one to demonstrate non-contiguous date ranges with same price
  ['start_date' => '2024-01-05', 'end_date' => '2024-01-05', 'price' => 600],
  ['start_date' => '2024-01-06', 'end_date' => '2024-01-07', 'price' => 700],
  ['start_date' => '2024-01-08', 'end_date' => '2024-01-20', 'price' => 700],
  ['start_date' => '2024-01-21', 'end_date' => '2024-01-31', 'price' => 100],
];

function mergeDateRangesByPrice($ranges)
{
  $output = [];
  $tempRange = [];
  foreach ($ranges as $i => $range) {

    if (empty($tempRange)) {
      $tempRange = $range;
      continue;
    }

    // If a new price is found, lock in the tempRange and re-assign
    if ($range['price'] !== $tempRange['price']) {
      $output[] = $tempRange;
      $tempRange = $range;

      // If this is the last element but a new price, add to output array
      if ($i == count($ranges)-1) {
        $output[] = $range;
      }
      continue;
    }

    $rangeStartDate = strtotime($range['start_date']);
    $tempRangeEndDatePlusOneDay = strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($tempRange['end_date']));

    // Contiguous end date/start date, update the end_date of the tempRange
    if ($tempRangeEndDatePlusOneDay === $rangeStartDate) {
      $tempRange['end_date'] = $range['end_date'];
      continue;
    }
    
    // Non-contiguous end date/start date, lock in the tempRange and reassign    
    $output[] = $tempRange;
    $tempRange = $range;
  }
  return $output;
} 

$output = mergeDateRangesByPrice($existingRanges);

var_export($output);
```

Yields:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'start_date' => '2023-11-22',
    'end_date' => '2023-11-30',
    'price' => 200,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'start_date' => '2023-12-10',
    'end_date' => '2023-12-20',
    'price' => 100,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'start_date' => '2023-12-22',
    'end_date' => '2023-12-27',
    'price' => 100,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'start_date' => '2024-01-05',
    'end_date' => '2024-01-05',
    'price' => 600,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'start_date' => '2024-01-06',
    'end_date' => '2024-01-20',
    'price' => 700,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'start_date' => '2024-01-21',
    'end_date' => '2024-01-31',
    'price' => 100,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function mergeDateRanges($p_arrDateranges) {
  // Sort by start date
  usort($p_arrDateranges, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['start_date']) - strtotime($b['start_date']);
  });

  $finalArray = [];

  foreach ($p_arrDateranges as $arrDR) {
    // If $finalArray is empty, add the first date range
    if (empty($finalArray)) {
      $finalArray[] = $arrDR;
      continue;
    }

    // Get the last date range in $finalArray
    $lastDR = end($finalArray);

    // Check if the current date range is adjacent and has the same price
    if (
      $arrDR['price'] === $lastDR['price'] &&
      strtotime($arrDR['start_date']) <= strtotime($lastDR['end_date']) + 86400 // Adding one day in seconds
    ) {
      // Merge the date ranges
      $lastDR['end_date'] = max($lastDR['end_date'], $arrDR['end_date']);
      $finalArray[count($finalArray) - 1] = $lastDR;
    } else {
      // Add the current date range to $finalArray
      $finalArray[] = $arrDR;
    }
  }

  return $finalArray;
}

$existingRanges = [
  // ... (your existing date ranges)
];

$results = mergeDateRanges($existingRanges);

print_r($results);
```

i've made some changes, you can go with this approach too!